# ¿Cómo buscar un archivo dentro de varias carpetas?

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo, buscador

Buenos Dias,

El problema que tengo es que necesito buscar uno o varios archivos dentro de una o varias carpetas

*Codigo1 :*

```
 String path = "C:\\Users\\ProKode\\Desktop\\PruebaBuscar";

    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)         {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())             {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
```

*Salida Codigo1:*

> run:
> Hola.txt
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

_

*Imagen de la Carpeta:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Que contiene lo siguiente:*
[image]

Dentro de la carpeta hay subcarpetas y dentro de ellas hay archivos

*Contenido de las carpetas:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir que no me esta buscando los archivos que hay dentro de las demas carpetas.

Lo que necesito es que me busque todo lo que esta dentro de la carpeta

*Salida Final:*

> Se encontro el archivo Hola.txt Dentro de la carpeta PruebaBuscar.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto1.1.txt Dentro de la carpeta Capeta1.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto1.2.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta1.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto1.3.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta1.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto2.1.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta2.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto2.2.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta2.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto2.3.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta2.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto3.1.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta3.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto3.2.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta3.
>
> Se encontro el archivo Texto3.3.txt Dentro de la carpeta Carpeta3.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás utilizando Java 7, puedes utilizar Java File IO (NIO.2). Es decir:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dir = "C:\\Users\\ProKode\\Desktop\\PruebaBuscar";
    String txt = "moises;diego;usuario";

    try {

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "\\A(?=.*" +  txt.replace(";", ")(?=.*") + ").*\\z", 
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(dir), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException {
                String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                if (pattern.matcher(str).matches()) {
                    System.out.println(file);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "IO Error", e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Prueba esta, llamada forma recursiva:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ListarArchivos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File miDir = new File("."); // directorio actual, cambiarlo si se quiere
        verContenidoFolder(miDir);
    }

    public static void verContenidoFolder(File dir) {
        try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("directorio:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    verContenidoFolder(file);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("     archivo:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, muchas gracias :D